# How do I use Rogers Nokia CS-18 rocket stick?

Tags: 10.10, networking, modem, 3g

I've just got a Rogers Nokia CS-18 rocket stick but when I plug it into my laptop it doesn't get recognized as a 3G modem.  I've rebooted and tried plugging it into windows first but nothing seems to work.

Why won't Ubuntu 10.10 detect this?

Comment: if you could add some logs it would help us out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Hey Jorge.  I actually just figured this one out.  See my comment below.  And thanks for all the work you do here.  I always see you around helping people like me out! :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, might be useful to add the info anyway for googleability in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't recreate the same hardware as it's effectively switched to a new USB device.  I'll make sure to include those details in my next question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to give thanks to @inhuman4 from the USB_ModeSwitch forums [for figuring this one out](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?t=524&sid=f8a1c18174423a1f2074f92aebcb32e5).

Basically, the modem acts like a USB key until a certain code is sent to it.  This code is device specific and Ubuntu uses usb_modeswitch to switch the mode on the modem from key to modem.

For the time being to add support for Rogers Nokia CS-18 rocketstick users need to add this to the bottom of `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/0421:0627`

```
######################################################## 
# Nokia CS-18 

DefaultVendor= 0x0421 
DefaultProduct=0x0627 

TargetVendor=  0x0421 
TargetProduct= 0x0612 

CheckSuccess=20 

MessageContent="5553424312345678000000000000061b000000020000000000000000000000"
```

Then they need to add this to `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`

```
# Nokia CS-18 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0421", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0627", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

That's it!  Unplug and replug your rocket stick and you are ready to go! :)

Hopefully these config file changes will be added to the Ubuntu distribution soon.

Comment: I got it to work on Lubuntu 11.10 using these steps.  Thanks!  Only  issue I found is that it does not recognize it automatically when I plug it in.  I have to manually activate it.